# Enable Browsec in WebKit WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webkit

I have a win application written in `C#` and I use WebKit as my Web Browser.

However, sometimes it cannot open url's that is blocked by Internet provider. But when I open the same URL in my Chrome browser with `Browsec` extension enabled, it opens up very well.

So I thought, is it possible to enable `Browsec` extension in my C# project's WebKit WebBrowser?
If yes, how to achieve it?